# Javascript Validation for Strings like b-0212

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm working on a project I want to do validation to an id which starts with a letter and then hyphen then a 4 digit number.

Examples : `a-0271`, `b-0261`.

Can someone please help me with jQuery/js code which can do validation for this type of `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

```
if(!/^[a-z]-\d{4}$/.test(value)){
    alert('not valid format')
}
```

- `/^` - Starting of the string
- `[a-z]` - an alphabet
- `-` followed by an `-`
- `\d{4}` - followed by 4 digits
- `$/` - end of string

Answer (score 0):

Use regex with vanilla JS:

```
if(/[a-z]-\d{4}/i.test(value) &&v value.length == 6){
   //Do stuff with valid value
}
```